# Already installed plotly but still can't import

Tags: python, config, plotly

I am trying to use plotly within Jupyter Notebook and have followed every step listed in the Getting Started with Plotly for Python [here](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/). I created a free account with plotly but when I try to import plotly and set my credentials in jupyter using my username and API, I continually see: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'.

Right on plotly's website it says to update my config file after regenerating my API key. However, I do not have a .plotly folder anywhere on my computer and therefore cannot find the .plotly/.config file to update the key. I'm on a work computer and have searched both my network drives and C: drive for the .plotly folder but I don't get any results.

I can see that plotly is installed:
[image: command line output for pip install plotly]

I've seen someone mention that maybe I've installed plotly where my python environment can't see it. Here is the pip show plotly output: [image: pip show plotly]. How can I check where I'm running python from?

I've also seen someone suggest checking where python is searching for modules using import sys. Here is that output below.  The very first filepath lists the plotly folder, which makes me think my issue is a configuration/API one.

[image: import sys/sys.path]

I also tried importing plotly using a specific file path and setting my credentials but get a different error. It says I cannot import 'exceptions' but I have an exceptions.py file in my plotly folder: [image: import plotly with filepath]

I am a Python novice and also not very familiar with command line. Can anyone point me in the right direction for trying to locate the .config plotly file if searching my computer for it turns up nothing?

Comment: Have you run pip, as per the installation section ? That is where the config folder/file would get installed.

Comment: Do a `pip freeze` this will show you all of the packages installed.

Comment: Hi @MikeW - yes, I have. You can see in the first picture above that plotly is installed.

Comment: Hi @SPYBUG96, pip freeze shows that plotly 3.4.0 is installed.

Comment: I would think the most important step to start with is the lack of your config file ...

Comment: @MikeW, I agree. That's why I'm asking for help in trying to locate it. If I've already installed plotly using pip and yet I don't have a config file, do you know of any steps to take to resolve this?

Comment: What about anaconda? I'm seeing in some output of yours. Are you using that?
Did you installed plotly inside of Anaconda?

Comment: OK, I ran the two-liner (see below) and it created my credential file. So if you cannot import from your other program it might be your PYTHONPATH is not set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some confusing things for the first sight: 
I see you may use **Anaconda** or you installed it previously. But you installed `plotly` in **pure Python** using `pip`.
If you have **Anaconda** installed, then I suggest you to use it. 
Start `anaconda-navigator` and [install plotly](https://anaconda.org/plotly/plotly) **inside of it**.
Then start your code or **Jupyter notebook** inside of the same **anaconda environment**.

For Example: If you run `jupyter` from `anaconda`, your code will not find `plotly` if you installed it in some pure python environment or some other anaconda environment.

**UPDATE:**
If you have the problem you mentioned below, without any knowledge regarding your system, I think the wisest action can be uninstall Anaconda and installing it again. There may be some problem around Anaconda and it should solve it.

Comment: Hi @Geeocode, I tried this but now I get an error that says 'ImportError: cannot import name 'offline'' when I attempt to import plotly in jupyter. Does this mean that the package was at least installed correctly? When I try to install plotly using Anaconda prompt, I get an 'Access Denied' error. When I try to install it directly in Anaconda Navigator, it spins like I'm installing it but then nothing shows up in my installed environments.

Comment: @Kelly the endless spinning could be due to the access error, I guess. I'm under linux now, so I can't simulate the error and when it can occur. Without any knowledge regarding your system, I think the wisest action can be uninstall Anaconda and installing it again. But If you can say why your access error occurs, which is weird under Windows, may exist other solution too.

Comment: thank you for the help. I had a feeling it has something to do with access. I have no idea how I would even go about figuring out where the access error is coming from so I'll try to reinstall Anaconda. Thanks again!

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling worked! Thanks again for the help. I should've tried this first.

Comment: @Kelly I'm happy to your success. I write though my comment in my answer, so you may accept it, if you think. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, having tried the steps:

- install plotly via pip
- run the two-line python program in the Installation guide

I seem to end up with a credentials file - it's the two-liner that creates this.

So check that you can import from the command shell python. If you can, then it's more likely it's a PYTHONPATH issue.

```
C:\Users\xxx>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import  plotly
>>> plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='DemoAccount', api_key='lr1c37zw81')
>>> quit()

C:\Users\xxx>dir .plotly
 Volume in drive C is OSDISK
 Volume Serial Number is DCCD-845E

 Directory of C:\Users\xxx\.plotly

09/11/2018  09:25    <DIR>          .
09/11/2018  09:25    <DIR>          ..
09/11/2018  09:25               302 .config
09/11/2018  09:25               142 .credentials
               2 File(s)            444 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  111,849,033,728 bytes free
```